# Bootstrap layout where column sits in align with multiple rows

Tags: bootstrap-4

What is the best way to achieve the following layout in Bootstrap (or to this affect)?

[image]

I wish to obviously keep this to Bootstrap standards and classes as much as possible but did not know how best to achieve this when it goes outside of the typical `container > row` layout.

I've got something like the below as things stand but it is proving difficult to get right...

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the following markup, you don't actually need any extra CSS. I added the `min-height` and some visual helpers to make them visible, but you don't need any of that, really. Unless your columns are empty, in which case you do need `min-height` accordingly.

```css
/* this is not, actually, needed */

[class*="col-"] {
  min-height: 60px;
}
[class*="col-"]:first-child, .col-md-9 [class*="col-"] {
  border: 1px solid #eee;
}
[class*="col-"]:first-child:hover, .col-md-9 [class*="col-"]:hover {
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3">
      1 of 2
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-9">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12 mb-md-3">
          2 of 2
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
          1 of 3
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
          2 of 3
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
          3 of 3
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

If you want to maintain the layout on `sm` as well, replace all `md`s with `sm`s. If you want to only keep it on `lg`, switch them to `lg`. Obviously, removing `md-`s from all cols will keep the layout on all widths, including mobile.

**Important note**: `col-*`s should only be children of `.row` or `.form-row` elements. This is well documented [here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/layout/grid/#how-it-works). If you don't respect it, you'll end up with broken layout on various devices and/or unexpected horizontal scrollbars.

Comment: After some playing around with it as per your answer, I've managed to get it spot on. Nice one :)

Comment: @zig, I simplified it a bit, you don't actually need two rows in second col, so I joined them. Cheers!

Comment: Cheers @tao mine scenario is more complex than the example code i originally posted so I think easier in my case to keep as two adjacent rows but I do see how your simplified version would work above as well - thanks.